# How to find some certain event handlers with jQuery?

Tags: controls, jquery

As many browsers do not show tooltips on disabled form elements (as Opera does), I decided to emulate disabled button with jQuery.

When disabling I just set control's class to disabled and for buttons/submit controls I add an event handler `click(function(){return false;})`
and I can unbind it later when reenabling the control.

Now the problem is - I need to remove all attached event handlers `(click, enter key)` from the disabled control, except 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' because I am using a custom jQuery based tooltip which needs those events. 
And after re enabling the button, I need to restore all handlers back.

I know that I can store the attached event handlers in `$.data()` but I have no idea, how to gather all the event handlers except 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<script>

$(function() {

//Lets attach 2 event handlers to the div
$("#el").click(function(){ alert("click"); });
$("#el").mouseover(function(){ alert("mouseover"); });


//We iterate on the div node and find the events attached to it

$.each($("#el").data("events"), function(i, event) {
    output(i);
    $.each(event, function(j, h) {
      output(h.handler);
      //DO your unbind here if its not a mouse-enter or a mouseleave
    });
  });
});

function output(text) {
    $("#output").html(function(i, h) {
        return h + text + "<br />";
    });
}

</script>

<div id="el" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: solid 1px red;">Test</div>
<span id="output"></output>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code together with event.type analysis did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

unbind - http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go to all that work.

Since you have a `.disabled` class on the disabled elements, I'd just use that as a flag to disabled/enable the functionality by testing for that class in an `if()` statement, and returning false if the element has the `disabled` class.

So using the `click` handler you gave, instead of:

```
$('someElement').click(function(){return false;});
```

I'd do this:

```
$('someElement').click(function() {
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // run your code
    }
});
```

Now when you remove the `.disabled` class, the input will work again. No `unbind/bind` or tracing using `.data()`. Much simpler.

Comment: Yes, this would be the most efficient solution, but it will force other developers who might write some event handlers, to remember to check for disabled status. I would like the enabler/disabler solution to be like some separate piece of code, most probably, jQuery plugin.